# SQLAlchemy delete cascade in both directions (without the ORM)

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have some models defined using `SQLAlchemy`'s ORM

```
class HasId(object):
    @declared_attr
    def id(cls):
        return Column('id', Integer, Sequence('test_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    ...

class TestParent(HasId, Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tests'
    discriminator = Column(String(50))
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': discriminator}
    ...


class FooTest(TestParent):
    __tablename__ = 'footests'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'footests'}
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tests.id'), primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('footests.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    children = relationship('FooTest',
                            foreign_keys='FooTest.parent_id',
                            lazy='joined',
                            join_depth=2,
                            cascade='save-update, merge, delete, delete-orphan')
    ...
```

When I delete a row from `tests` (The `TestParent` model) *when not using the ORM*, the corresponding row in `footests` gets deleted. All good.

I would like to be able to delete a row from `footests` *outside of the ORM* and have the corresponding row in `tests` to be deleted. This is essentially getting the cascade to work in the opposite direction.

Is this possible outside of the ORM? Is there another way to think about this? (database engine is `MySQL / Mariadb`)

Comment: How are you inserting and deleting?

Comment: @univerio, I am currently interacting with the db using a GUI. I edited my question to ask if this is possible without the ORM.

Answer (score 1):

This should just work if you add/delete with the ORM:

```
>>> foo = FooTest()
>>> session.add(foo)
>>> session.flush()
>>> list(session.execute("SELECT * FROM tests;"))
[(u'footests', 1)]
>>> list(session.execute("SELECT * FROM footests;"))
[(1, None)]
>>> session.delete(foo)
>>> session.flush()
>>> list(session.execute("SELECT * FROM tests;"))
[]
>>> list(session.execute("SELECT * FROM footests;"))
[]
```

Comment: do you think there is a way to define this cascade within MySQL (without using the ORM)? I spend a lot of time using the database gui during development.

Comment: @BrianLeach You can add a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html) to do this.